# Проблема с перебором списка

Tags: python, python-2.x

Хочу перебрать список и дополнить вывод чисел буквами.

результат должен быть таким

```
1st  
2nd  
3rd  
4th  
…
```

```py
items = [range(1, 9)]
for item in items:
    if item == 1:
        print(str(item)+'st')
    elif item == 2:
        print(str(item)+'nd')
    elif item == 3:
        print(str(item)+'rd')
    else:
        print(str(item)+'th')
```

При запуске программы выводит список целиком и выводит результат огбработки else

результат:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]th
```

может кто подсказать в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: С перебором списка проблем нет. Проблема в том, что в списке не то, что ты думаешь. Убери квадратные скобки. Учись искать элементарные ошибки самостоятельно. Можно было бы начать например с ``print(items)``. И форматируй код в вопросах нормально.

Comment: Благодарю, код почему то здесь криво отобразился, так отступы соблюдены в редакторе. Реально затупил что нужно без скобок.

Comment: for item in range(1, 10): должно помочь

Comment: @ИльяСтешенко Если бы вы написали `list(range(...`, то проблемы бы не было

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственная ошибка - неверное заполнение `items`.
Исправьте `items = [range(1, 10)]` на `items = list(range(1, 10))`

---

Но я бы делал так:

```py
postfix = {
    1: 'st',
    2: 'nd', 
    3: 'rd',
}

for item in range(1, 10):
    print(item, postfix.get(item, 'th'), sep='')
```

---

Немного "извращений":

```
for item in range(1, 10):
    print(item, {1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'}.get(item, 'th'), sep='')
```

Comment: можно просто `range(1, 10)`

Comment: @Danis да, но тогда  `items` будет "одноразовым"

Comment: в [tag:python-2.x] `range` возвращает просто список, а в [tag:python-3.x] `range` это не генератор и по нему можно итерировать многократно

Comment: @Danis спасибо. упустил как-то этот момент